# Long delay for Google Voice prompt if dialed from "Contact" home screen shortcut

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, phone-app, google-voice

I have Google Voice set up to prompt me (whether to dial using GV) every time I make a call (in GV app `Settings -> Making calls -> Ask every time I make a call`.)

When I dial via the Phone app, or via "Direct dial" home screen shortcut, the "Google Voice" prompt appears instantaneously.  However, if I add a "Contact" shortcut to my home screen, tap it and select any number to dial, the same prompt takes over 5 seconds to pop up.  The logs are showing no other activity during this time:

```
I/ActivityManager(  223): Displayed com.android.contacts/.quickcontact.QuickContactActivity: +332ms
I/ActivityManager(  223): START {act=android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED dat=tel:xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.PrivilegedOutgoingCallBroadcaster} from pid 2814
D/PhoneUtils(  636): checkAndCopyPhoneProviderExtras: some or all extras are missing.
D/dalvikvm(  223): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2189K, 18% free 23216K/28103K, paused 2ms+6ms
I/ActivityManager(  223): START {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/.CallConnectingActivity (has extras)} from pid 1646
D/dalvikvm(  636): GC_EXPLICIT freed 107K, 4% free 13700K/14215K, paused 2ms+4ms
D/OpenGLRenderer(  636): Flushing caches (mode 1)
D/OpenGLRenderer( 2814): Flushing caches (mode 0)
I/ActivityManager(  223): Displayed com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/.CallConnectingActivity: +5s25ms (total +5s167ms)
```

Specifically, the line `I/ActivityManager(  223): Displayed com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/.CallConnectingActivity:`**+5s11ms**`(total +5s302ms)` shows the actual "lag" time.

I cannot see anything different than if I try dialing out from a "Direct Dial" type of a shortcut:

```
D/dalvikvm(  612): GC_CONCURRENT freed 607K, 7% free 15178K/16199K, paused 3ms+16ms
I/ActivityManager(  223): START {act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster bnds=[185,50][360,250]} from pid 671
D/PhoneUtils(  636): checkAndCopyPhoneProviderExtras: some or all extras are missing.
D/dalvikvm(  758): GC_CONCURRENT freed 423K, 5% free 13369K/13959K, paused 1ms+4ms
I/ActivityManager(  223): START {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/.CallConnectingActivity (has extras)} from pid 1646
D/dalvikvm(  636): GC_EXPLICIT freed 210K, 4% free 13690K/14215K, paused 3ms+4ms
D/OpenGLRenderer(  636): Flushing caches (mode 1)
I/ActivityManager(  223): Displayed com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/.CallConnectingActivity: +265ms (total +354ms)
```

I am running CM9 alpha (ICS: Android 4.0.3) on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone, but the same thing was happening on my Atrix 4G running stock Gingerbread (Android 2.3.4) and CM7 (Android 2.3.5.)  This makes me think that this is not a general Android issue, but rather a bug in Google Voice app.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem?  Other than posting on GV feedback forums, how do I go about resolving this?

Comment: I went ahead and posted on Google's GV forums as well: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/voice/making-and-receiving-calls/ikNAywCY5q8  Hopefully someone "official" will chime in.

Comment: This has been resolved in Android 4.1 Jelly Bean.  Still no idea what's causing it on earlier OS versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved in Android 4.1, a.k.a. "Jelly Bean".  Now Google Voice prompt appears instantly no matter how it's triggered.  Since the Google Voice app has not changed, my original thinking that it's the app's fault was incorrect.

Still no idea what's causing it on earlier OS versions.